# numpy vstack empty initialization

Tags: python, numpy

I have vstacked image data and now I wish to split this in a training and test set.
However how do I initialize an empty numpy array so I can start vstacking?

My simplified code looks like this:

```
#k-fold the data
kf = cross_validation.KFold(n, n_folds=2)
fold = 0
for train_ind, test_ind in kf:
    #Get the persons of k-fold
    train_pers = unique[train_ind]
    test_pers = unique[test_ind]
    
    #Set train+test stack to empty
    self.train_stack = type(self.pca_data[0])
    self.test_stack = type(self.pca_data[0])
            
    #For all test data
    for data in range(len(self.pca_data)):
        print(self.pca_pers[data])
        if self.pca_pers[data] in train_pers:
            #Add to train stack
            self.train_stack = np.vstack((self.train_stack, self.pca_data[data]))
            
        elif self.pca_pers[data] in test_pers:
            #Add to test stack
            self.test_stack = np.vstack((self.test_stack, self.pca_data[data]))
        else:
            #Something wrong
            print(data)
            sys.exit("Strange strange data")
            
    fold += 1
```

The import code here is:

```
#Set train+test stack to empty
self.train_stack = type(self.pca_data)
self.test_stack = type(self.pca_data)
```

and

```
#Add to train stack
self.train_stack = np.vstack((self.train_stack, self.pca_data[fold][data]))
```

*self.pca_data* contains all the image data, this data has to be distributed over *self.train_stack* and *self.test_stack*. I tried the *type()* function, but this seems to be wrong. I also tried *self.train_stack = []*, but this raises the error "ValueError: array dimensions must agree except for d_0". If I would use numpy.zeros, then the first stack are 0's, and I want it to be completely empty before vstacking.

### Question

What is the right way to initialize an empty numpy array? (type 'numpy.ndarray')

p.s. Note that the *self.train_stack* is in a loop, so an if statement, for if the variable doesn't exist, will not reset the variable when entering the loop for the 2nd time.

### Variables

- self.pca_data: Shape(978, 20) Type(type 'numpy.ndarray')
- self.pca_pers: Shape(978, 1) Type(type 'numpy.ndarray')
- self.test_stack and self.train_stack should be for e.g. Shape(489, 20) and Shape(489, 20) like self.pca_data
- Other variables you can ignore

Comment: Please tell us which variables are scalars and which are arrays, and the shape of those which are arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid calling `np.vstack` in a loop. Each time you do this, 
a new array is allocated, and 
all the data from the original aray and the new row is *copied* into the new array.
All that copying makes such a solution slower than necessary.

If we can assume that every row of `self.pca_data` belongs in either `self.train_stack` or `self.test_stack`, then you could replace the entire `for-loop`

```
for data in range(len(self.pca_data)):
    ...
```

with a call to [np.in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to create a boolean mask, and then
define `self.train_stack` and `self.test_stack` by indexing `self.pca_data` using the mask:

```
for fold, (train_ind, test_ind) in enumerate(kf):
    train_pers = unique[train_ind]
    mask = np.in1d(self.pca_pers[:,0], train_pers)
    self.train_stack = self.pca_data[mask]
    self.test_stack = self.pca_data[~mask]
```

---

For example, `np.in1d` creates a boolean array which is `True` when the element
in the first array-like is in the second array-like:

```
In [544]: np.in1d(range(5), [1,2,4])
Out[544]: array([False,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

and boolean indexing can be used to select rows like this:

```
In [545]: mask = np.in1d(range(5), [1,2,4])

In [546]: x = np.arange(10).reshape(5,-1)

In [547]: x
Out[547]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])

In [548]: x[mask]
Out[548]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [8, 9]])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a much more effective way than I was trying to do. Some other part of my code I don't have the luxury that I have all the data, but I get it 1 image by 1 image. Do you know in that case how you can initialize a variable for np.vstack()?

Comment: You could use `self.train_stack = np.empty((0, self.pca_data.shape[1]), dtype=self.pca_data.dtype)`, though it might be rather slow. If you have the memory, it would be faster to append the rows to a list, and then simply call `np.array` **once** (after the loop completes) to turn the list of rows into a 2D array.

Comment: Thanks that was I was looking for! I knew there was some simple solution to it. I keep that advice in my mind :)